# Can you explain how "django.contrib.auth" works to me please?

Tags: django

I'm working on an authentication module drawing inspiration from and replacing "django.contrib.auth".

What are they doing with all this and why?

```
def get_user(request):
  from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
  try:
    user_id = request.session[SESSION_KEY]
    backend_path = request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY]
    backend = load_backend(backend_path)
    user = backend.get_user(user_id) or AnonymousUser()
  except KeyError:
    user = AnonymousUser()
  return user

class LazyUser(object):
  def __get__(self, request, obj_type=None):
    if not hasattr(request, '_cached_user'):
        from django.contrib.auth import get_user
        request._cached_user = get_user(request)
    return request._cached_user

class AuthenticationMiddleware(object):
  def process_request(self, request):
    assert hasattr(request, 'session'), "The Django authentication ..."
    request.__class__.user = LazyUser()
    return None
```

- Is it trying to prevent a database hit for the user instance on every request?
- Does it go stale if the user record is altered?
- Why don't they simply save the user instance, or a key to it, in the session?
- why assign to `request.__class__.user` and not simply `request.user`?

I'd add the authenticate, login, and logout routines but don't want to bore you with too many code dumps.  I think I get it now, (that last question might be the key) but only by having forced myself to lay out the question (somewhat) sensibly :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No. It pulls the user at most once per request, but does not span requests.
2. Yes.
3. They do. The store the PK.
4. So that it becomes a class attribute of `request` (as opposed to an instance attribute), which allows it to work correctly as a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors).

Comment: Why only put just the key in the session and not the whole User object?

Comment: Because putting an entire object in the session is not straightforward, plus (although this very, very rarely happens) the entire class used for the user could change under it, leading to strange bugs.

Comment: I think it is also because of session related security concerns.

Comment: How so? The PK is all that's needed to identify a user.

Comment: First of is it not a random hash value that gets put into the session and not the primary key. Someone could capture, or forge(cookie-forging) information in you session that might cause potential problem.

Comment: Other than the session ID, the session lives entirely on the server. If you have people reading and writing arbitrary session data then you have bigger problems than a user being spoofed.

Comment: Hmm. When I made my initial comment I was just adding to your reason for why the entire User object is not stored in the session. We seem to be pushing the same points, so maybe there was just some miscommunication.

Comment: @Ignacio "not straightforward"? The current django documentation states: "The session dictionary should accept any pickleable Python object."